# Convert base64 to string using base64.b64decode method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert some nontypical string (encoded by base64) to decoded string. I was trying with:

```
valueDecoded = base64.b64decode(value)
```

but got `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`.

code example:

```
value = "MIIFpjCCBI6gAwIBAgIIJUTbvTn6KuQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwgZYxCzA"
valueDecoded = base64.b64decode(value)
```

[Online converters](http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/) have no problems with this value.

How to decode it with Python?

Comment: But if you do a back and fort conversion on the online convert, you see, that he can read it but doesnt like it.

Comment: Try adding an additional `=` or two and then trying to decode it, it seems like it's worked on Python 3.6.2.

Comment: Yes, it was problem with `=` on the end. Thank you all!